# Exclude some SonarQube rules for certain files in sonar.properties

Tags: sonarqube

I know it is possible to exclude some rules for certain files in the SonarQube UI but I did not find anything about excluding this in the `sonar.properties` file.

Everything I found was how to exclude files and directories for all rules, but is it possible to restrict this to only one rule in the `sonar.properties`?